# What's the easiest way to create a unique job for every worker of monero mining pool?

Tags: monerod, mining-pools, random-x

There are several mining pool servers.

Each server polls monerod for a new job.

I want to generate a **unique** job on each server for all the workers of my distributed pool.

It is very important to note that I want to generate unique **among all my servers**.

What is the simplest to do this?

Would it be the simplest way to use an algorithm similar to this [algorithm](https://github.com/jtgrassie/monero-pool/blob/master/src/pool.c#L1261) from the sources of mining pool implementation? (and the question of uniqueness interests me the most)

1. Generate a server ID (4 bytes).
2. Use extra nonce integer (4 bytes).
3. And put this (1, 2) as extra data of miner’s transaction.
4. Regenerate
   hashing blob by using [parse_and_validate_block_from_blob](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/9f3e8e3ff08c2bbdd4fa2da3797811531970171f/src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp#L1351) and
   [get_block_hashing_blob](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/9f3e8e3ff08c2bbdd4fa2da3797811531970171f/src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp#L1235) functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Monero pool I know of (including the pool you linked), reserves 32 bytes in the block template for the purposes of dealing with job uniqueness, which is laid out something like:

```
job_nonce | instance_nonce | pool_nonce | worker_nonce
```

Here, `job_nonce` would be unique to the job, `instance_nonce` unique to the server and lastly `pool_nonce` and `worker_nonce` is space a mining proxy can use.

Thus each server, as you correctly observe, needs to use a unique `instance_nonce` (per the example above). It doesn't matter what it is, but it needs to be unique. The simplest way of achieving this is to read 4 random bytes. This can be read from `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`, or anything which sources random data (such as a UUID). Alternatively you could set an instance ID via a pool config file, removing the need to create a random ID, but you'd have to make sure each pool was configured with it's own unique ID.

If you don't need to support proxies, you don't need to reserve the space for the proxy related nonces.

> What is the simplest to do this?

Simplest is probably reading 4 bytes from `/dev/random`.