# Can the expected reward from the block template differ from a actual one after mining?

Tags: monerod, mining, mining-pools, rpc

As we know, we can find a value `expected_reward` in a response of a request `getblocktemplate` to a monerod.

Following the [documentation](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_block_template):

```
expected_reward - unsigned int; Coinbase reward expected to be received if block is successfully mined.
```

I have a couple of questions here:

1. Can be the `expected_reward` value of potentially new block can be
   differ to a actual block reward after it was mined and confirmed?
2. How is a `expected_reward` value obtained? Did I understand correctly that the answer to this question is written [here](https://github.com/JollyMort/monero-research/blob/master/Monero%20Dynamic%20Block%20Size%20and%20Dynamic%20Minimum%20Fee/Monero%20Dynamic%20Block%20Size%20and%20Dynamic%20Minimum%20Fee%20-%20DRAFT.md) and [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/4092/10511)?

Answer (score 1):

1) So long as you don't edit the block template returned (i.e. you don't add a load more data or change the transactions included), `expected_reward` is what you would receive if you mined a block based on that template.

If you added or removed transactions, the fees collected would obviously change. If you changed the overall size of the block (added more data to extra for example), the reward calculation could be affected (e.g. the penalty fee could kick-in).

2) The links you referenced are both outdated (2017). Please see [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/11639/7493), which references newer information.

Comment: I would like to clarify about the first point. You mean by “change the transactions included” if another transaction is added to the list of transactions or one of the transactions changes?

Comment: If I ask for a block template with a 4-bytes reserved size. And I will change these 4 bytes per workers using, for example, `/dev/random` (as you suggested here https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/12201/whats-the-easiest-way-to-create-a-unique-job-for-every-worker-of-monero-mining). Will the block reward per worker be the same as `expected_reward` from my rpc request (which I did only once)? I request a block template with only 4 reserved bytes and only modify them.

Comment: “change the transactions included” < If you added/removed txs, the fees would change. If you added a significant amount of data (to say the miner tx extra), the reward may get affected by penalty fee.

Comment: "If I ask for a block template with a 4-bytes reserved size" < 4 bytes would be highly unlikely to change the reward. And in any case, as you requested those 4 bytes they are already factored into the expected_reward, so as long as you don't add more bytes, the expected_reward will not change.